# Setting a function and all its derivatives to zero

Tags: replacement, calculus-and-analysis

Define a function of two variables with a partial derivative

```
X[q_, p_] := t[q, p]*p^2 + D[t[q, p], {p, 2}]
```

I want to tell *Mathematica* that `t[q,p]` is the zero function, so that it and all its derivatives are zero. However if I do the naive thing

```
X[q, p] /. t[q, p] -> 0
```

the result is

```
t^(0,2)[q, p]
```

so *Mathematica* doesn't take the derivatives to be zero. Is it possible to do a replacement, such that it will take them to be zero?

**LATE UPDATE**

If we define

```
A[x_, z_] := Sum[ax[j, z]*x^j, {j, 0, 4}];
m[x_, z_] := A[x, z]*(1 - z^2) + D[A[x, z], z]*87 + D[A[x, z], {z, 2}]/(1 + x^2)
expr = 2*m[x, z]
```

followed by

```
ax[1, z_] := 0;
```

, typing `expr` and then evaluating it, it still contains terms like `ax^(0,1)[1, z]` and `ax^(0,2)[1, z]`. Same applies for `m[x,z]`. How to resolve that? Although, I have the feeling that there should be a better way of indexing sums.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `t[q_, p_] := 0`? That's the first idea that came to my mind.

Comment: Ah, ok, that works. Maybe I should really go to bed now...

Comment: There is a phase transition where the code actually starts getting worse as you keep working on it despite being exhausted. Optimize your resting periods too!

Comment: Is it possible to do that with a replacement `/.`, though?

Comment: `/. t[q,p] -> Function[{q, p}, 0]`?

Comment: `X[q, p] /. t -> Function[{q, p}, 0]` seems to work at least in version 7.

Comment: Yep, it works in version 11 as well. I am trying something with dummy indices now, so might come back tomorrow to this again. Thank you guys!

Comment: Ah, of course.  That's what I get for posting without actually trying it!

Comment: I edited my question, but I don't think anybody has reviewed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you have a function called `X`, which depends on another function `t`. In practice, when you call them they will appear as heads in compound expressions such as, say, `X[1,2]` or `t[0,0]`. If you want to replace the function called `t` with a zero function using replacement, then you can do it by replacing the head `t`.

```
X[q_, p_] := t[q, p]*p^2 + D[t[q, p], {p, 2}]
X[q, p] /. t -> Function[{q, p}, 0]
(*0*)
```

Above, it is important to replace `t` with the zero function of two arguments. **EDIT** As pointed out by m_goldberg, it is also possible to use the short form of pure functions, in which case you don't need to worry about the number of arguments:

```
X[q, p] /. t -> (0 &)
(*0*)
```

**end EDIT** If using replacement is not required, then the straigthforward approach would be to simply set `t[q_, p_] := 0`, but in case you want to set `t` to be the zero function only temporarily then a natural alternative is to use `Block`.

```
Block[{t = Function[{q, p}, 0]}, X[q, p]]
(*0*)
```

You could also use `With[{t = Function[{q, p}, 0]}, Evaluate@X[q, p]]` but `Block` is the more appropriate scoping construct here.

Comment: You might want add the simple form `x[q, p] /. t -> (0 &)` to your discussion.

Comment: I updated my questions with another situation, where the above approach doesn't seem to work